# Component does not get cleared when values are reset

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

I have a child component as follows,

**Child component.html**

```
 <div >
        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" (click)="toggleDropdown()">
            {{ slectedItemName }} <span ></span>
        </button>
        <div *ngIf="showDropdown>
            <ul class="default-dropdown">
                <li *ngFor="let item of list" (click)="onSelectItem(item.value)" [ngClass]="{'active': item.value==selected}">
                    <a>{{item.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Child component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
declare const _: any;
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'dropdown',
  templateUrl: 'dropdown.component.html'
})
export class DropdownComponent {
  @Input() list: any;
  @Input() selected: string;
  @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter<any>();
  showDropdown: boolean;
  slectedItemName: string;
  constructor() {
    this.showDropdown = false;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.setSelected(this.selected);
  }
  setSelected(selected: string) {
    const selectedItem = _.find(this.list, (item: any) => {
      return item.value === selected;
    });
    this.slectedItemName = selectedItem.name;
  }
  toggleDropdown() {
    this.showDropdown = !this.showDropdown;
  }
  onSelectItem(selected: string) {
    this.onSelect.emit(selected);
    this.setSelected(selected);
    this.toggleDropdown();
  }
}
```

I am using this child component in the parent component as follows,

```
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 search-filter-buttongroup-wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li class="timeframe">
                        <dropdown [list]="allRegions" [selected]="selectedRegion" (onSelect)="onSelectRegion($event)">
                        </dropdown>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="clear-text header-search-block-text" (click)="clearFilters()">
                        <span><img src="../imgs/reset.svg">Clear Filters</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

when changing the dropdown values are setting correctly, on clicking clear filters i am resetting the values. but the value changes are not getting reflected on the parent component. it still shows the selected values.
this is the function to clear the selected values.

```
  clearFilters() {    
    this.selectedRegion = '';
  }
```

what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't update `selectedItemName`
use this instead of `@Input()selected:string`:

```
  selected:string;
  @Input("selected") 
  set _selected(selected: string){
    this.selected = selected;
    if(this.list){
      const selectedItem = _.find(this.list, (item: any) => {
        return item.value === selected;
      });
      this.slectedItemName = selectedItem.name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry that was just a pile of crap, here is the solution

Comment: it's a setter, called everytime the `@Input()` is changed.

Comment: because you set `selectedItemName` only on init and on selection, then if the `@Input() selected:string` changes, it is not updated. the setter runs every time you want to set the property `_selected` (which didn't exist yet) and the `@Input('selected')` rename it to "selected" for external use: `<my-component [selected]="selected">` here `selected` actually refers to `_selected`.